# Ajax search not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I'm searching in an XML file for certain items that contain the substring which is in the input field. The search works at first, but if i delete the input and write things again it doesn't work anymore. I'm creating a table row for every item found, because I need to use them later. I also delete a row from the table if the item no longer matches the search input. BTW, I know that reading like this from an XML doesn't work in CHROME but i am using Firefox to check.

My script:

```
<script>
  var inTable = new Set();

  function showResult(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) {
      document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border = "0px";
      return;
    }
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xhttp, str);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "Menu.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();
  }

  function myFunction(xml, str) {
    var tbody = document.getElementById('livesearch');
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ITEM");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      a = x[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.toString();
      if (a.toLowerCase().indexOf(str) != -1) {
        if (inTable.has(a) == false) {
          console.log("add to table");
          inTable.add(a);
          var tr = document.createElement('tr');
          tr.setAttribute('name', a);
          var td = document.createElement('td');
          td.innerHTML = x[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
          tr.appendChild(td);
          td = document.createElement('td');
          td.innerHTML = x[i].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
          tr.appendChild(td);
          td = document.createElement('td');
          td.innerHTML = x[i].getElementsByTagName("DESC")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
          tr.appendChild(td);
          tr.setAttribute('onclick', 'changeSomething();');
          tbody.appendChild(tr);
        } else console.log("it exists in table");
      } else if (inTable.has(a) == true) {
        console.log("deletes from table");
        inTable.delete(a);
        var y = document.getElementsByName(a)[0];
        tbody.deleteRow(y.rowIndex);
      }
    }
  }
  changeSomething = function() {
    document.getElementById('demo').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }

</script>
```

HTML part:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">
  <table id="livesearch"></table>
  <div id="demo"></div>
</form>
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<MENU>
    <ITEM>
        <NAME>CARTOFI PRAJITI</NAME>
        <PRICE>6 LEI</PRICE>
        <DESC>300 g</DESC>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <NAME>PASTRAV INVELIT IN SUNCA AFUMATA</NAME>
        <PRICE>43 lei</PRICE>
        <DESC>Pastrav</DESC>
    </ITEM>

</MENU>
```

Thanks.

Comment: hi... a sample xml would be helpful if not mandatory to help You

Comment: Dose Ajax call whenever fire keyup event ?

Comment: Yes it seems it does. The problem seems to be with how i handle the set i think.

Comment: Maybe myFunction has a problem logic.
try debug in source tab of chrome dev tools. (use breakpoint at a suspected line.)

Comment: ... here works good even on chrome, just do not leave `a` var in the wild and do a basic check on `y` with something like `y && tbody.deleteRow(y.rowIndex);`           
[see it here](http://freakstyle.it/stack/36764056/)

Comment: It's not working there either. If you clear the input and try it again there won't be any results shown. It only works the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clear Set when length of str is zero.

add 'inTable.clear();'

```
if (str.length == 0) {
  document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border = "0px";
  inTable.clear();
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working. Can you explain why the set isn't empty if i delete the items from it when i find them?

Comment: Ok, wait until tomorrow;; I am eating a drink now.

Comment: Even when input value is zero(""), intable has data. so your code don't add DOM. I think you should rewrite if condition part of your code.